# Remove space in Emails

Tags: line-breaking, line-spacing

In a paper I need to remove spaces between two emails of an author with two affiliations. The code is below:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article} 
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
Author Name\\
Affiliation1\\
Affiliation2\\
City/Country\\
{\tt\scriptsize mail1} \\ % here there is almost a space of a full line
{\tt\scriptsize mail2}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I have tried to put a `\vspace{-1}` after `mail1} \\`, but did not work. Also I tried to put both emails in same `{}` environment but could not find a way to put line break inside it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Here's a suggestion: Instead of posting a code snippet like that, please provide us with a complete, [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates the problem. Helping us in this way, really helps you in the end.

Comment: For future reference, please make your code _minimal_. Are things like font size, paper size, title, etc. relevant to your question?

Comment: @paulsimmons Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Since you're using LaTeX, see [Does it matter if I use `\textit` or `\it`, `\bfseries` or `\bf`, etc.](http://goo.gl/ECK5V) and [Will two-letter font style commands (`\bf`, `\it`, …) ever be resurrected in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/u98NT)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to (a) specify a *negative amount* of additional spacing following the first email address -- as is also suggested in @sverre's earlier answer -- and (b) encase the author-related information in an `\author` directive.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{Author Name\\
Affiliation1\\
Affiliation2\\
City/Country\\
{\scriptsize\texttt{emailaddress1}}\\[-0.7ex] %% choose the amount of spacing adjustment here
{\scriptsize\texttt{emailaddress2}}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Class `article` puts the author entry into a `tabular`:

```
\large
% ...
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
  \@author
\end{tabular}\par}%
```

And LaTeX adds struts to ensure a uniform line spacing in the `tabular`. Thus the mail addresses are set with `\scriptsize`, but the struts are added for `\large`.

One way to solve the issue: The mail addresses are put into a nested `tabular` with size `\scriptsize`. Then the struts of the nested `tabular` are smaller according to `\scriptsize`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\begin{document}
\title{Title}
\author{%
  Author Name\\
  Affiliation1\\
  Affiliation2\\
  City/Country\\
  \scriptsize
  \ttfamily
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    mail1\\
    mail2
  \end{tabular}
}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}
\begin{document}
Author Name\\
Affiliation1\\
Affiliation2\\
City/Country\\
{\tt\scriptsize mail1}\\
[-1ex]
{\tt\scriptsize mail2}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the full title-making mechanism `\maketitle`, then you should use the full title-making mechanism. The title is stored using `\title`, authors and their affiliations are stored using `\author`, and date (if needed) is added using `\date`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article} 

\title{Title}
\author{%
  Author Name \\
  Affiliation1 \\
  Affiliation2 \\
  City/Country \\[-1ex]
  \texttt{\scriptsize mail1} \\[-1ex]
  \texttt{\scriptsize mail2}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

A vertical adjustment is made using `\\[<len>]` where `<len>` can be any length. Specifying a negative length moves the contents vertically upwards.

Since an `\author` merely sets its contents in a centred `tabular`, you can also add multiple authors in the following way, if ever needed:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article} 

\title{Title}
\author{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Author Name1 \\
    Affiliation1 \\
    Affiliation2 \\
    City/Country \\[-1ex]
    \texttt{\scriptsize mail1} \\[-1ex]
    \texttt{\scriptsize mail2}
  \end{tabular}\quad%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Author Name2 \\
    Affiliation1 \\
    Affiliation2 \\
    City/Country \\[-1ex]
    \texttt{\scriptsize mail1} \\[-1ex]
    \texttt{\scriptsize mail2}
  \end{tabular}\quad%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
    Author Name3 \\
    Affiliation1 \\
    City/Country \\[-1ex]
    \texttt{\scriptsize mail1}
  \end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```